# PHP is this possible when the function is called only return the value thats in the link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

currently i use jquery ui TABS

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
$('#tabs').tabs({
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        window.location.hash = ui.newPanel.selector;
    }
});

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="input" action="post.php" target="my_iframe1" method="post">
Summoner Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Region:<select name="region">
<option value="euw">Western Europe</option>
<option value="eune">North Europe</option>
<option value="na">North America</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ranked">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    ed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

post.php data

```
//home
echo "<pre>";
echo "<h2>Summoner Info</h2>";

foreach ($str3 as $objects) {
   echo "<pre>";
   $name = $str3->name;
   $level = $str3->summonerLevel;
   $prid = $str3->profileIconId;
   $imglink = "http://lkimg.zamimg.com/shared/riot/images/profile_icons/profileIcon".$prid.".jpg";
    echo("<table border='1'><tr><th>Summoner Icon </th><th>Summoner Name </th><th>Summoner Level </th></tr>\n");
    echo("<tr><td><center><img width='32px' height='32px' src=\"$imglink\" alt=\"Cover\"></center></td><td><center>$name</center></td><td><center>$level</center></td>\n");
    echo("</table>");


   break;
}
//ranked
echo "<pre>";
echo "<h2>Ranked Stats</h2>";
foreach($str4['champions'] as $row){

    //get the values, dont really need to reassign but you get the idea
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $played = $row['stats']['totalSessionsPlayed'];
    $lost = $row['stats']['totalSessionsLost'];
    $won = $row['stats']['totalSessionsWon'];
    $imglink = "http://lkimg.zamimg.com/shared/riot/images/champions/".$id."_32.png";

if ($name == "Combined"){
$totalplayed = $row["stats"]["totalSessionsPlayed"];
$totallost = $row["stats"]["totalSessionsLost"];
$totalwon = $row["stats"]["totalSessionsWon"];
continue;
}
    echo("<font color='white'>");
    echo("<table  border='1'><tr><th>Champion</th><th>Games Played</th><th>Won</th><th>Lost</th></tr>\n");
    echo("<tr><td><img width='32px' height='32px' src=\"$imglink\" alt=\"Cover\"></td><td><center>$played</center></td><td><center>$won</center></td><td><center>$lost</center></td>\n");
    echo("</table>");

}
echo("<table border='1'>");
echo("<tr><th>Total Games Played</th><th>Won</th><th>Lost</th></tr>\n");
echo("<tr><td><center>$totalplayed</center></td><td><center>$totalwon</center></td><td><center>$totallost</center></td>\n");
echo("</table>");
```

so what im looking for is hide the tabs when submitted to post.php make the tabs appear but when switched to tab 3 which is #ranked that it only pulls the data under //ranked and when i switch to home that it only uses the data under //home is this possible?

so its like preloaded but when you switch tabs it shows different data

greetings

Comment: Just do it with jquery. Look at this: `https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ `

Comment: Could you help me with it as im quite inexperienced

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript events to check on when the user submits or whether they switch tabs. Seeing that you're already using jQuery, why not just listen for these events easily using: $("element").on('change', callback)

This will help in reducing number of communications to the back-end.

Comment: im quite new to jquery so im kinda having no clue sorry if i sound dumb